# Unity - Load options additive to the ingame scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

at first, my most important research for this topic:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html

When I start my game from the main menu I get into the "Ingame" scene. The ingame scene got an ingame menu with some buttons. I can click an "Options" button there.

So from the main menu I start the game by this method:

```
public void StartGame()
    {
        LoadScene("Ingame", LoadSceneMode.Single); // Load the main scene of the game
    }
```

So when I open up my ingame menu and click on the options button I call this method

```
public void LoadOptions()
    {
        LoadScene("Options", LoadSceneMode.Additive); // Don't destroy the game and load the options menu
    }
```

This works fine, because it doesn't destroy the ingame scene. But the problem is, that all objects are kept to the options scene. That is not, what I have expected.

How can I get into the options scene without my ingame objects and get back to the ingame scene when finishing the options?

Thanks :)

Comment: That's how additive works as I believe. It loads additional scene without destroying the existing one. I'm guessing your problem is the objects in the in-game scene gets loaded again when you go back to it. If that's the case, what you need to do id track all the GOs from the option scene and destroy it when you want to be in the ingame scene without loading the in-game scene.

Comment: FWIW, using scenes to navigate between menus is a bad idea. Try getting all menus into the same scene and enabling/disabling them as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Once you are done with your Options scene, you can change your active scene back to your game and unload the menu scene.  It will look something like this.

```
Scene gameScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Ingame");
SceneManager.SetActiveScene(gameScene);
SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("Options");
```